# How do I replicate document approval workflow in Announcement list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, approval-process, content-approval, announcements

I have requirement where I want to create workflow for **Announcement** list. The clear cut requirement is, when any user creates any announcements, it should first go from **Approval** process.

If the approver approves the item then and then only it should be visible to all other user.

I tried creating workflow for **Announcement** list by following [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/document-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013/) article(Given link is for document library).

But I am not able to find the option of Approval workflow in the `Workflow settings` of **Announcement** list.

So, If any one has gone through this requirement then please share any reference link or short guide to accomplish it.

The question may sound silly, but I really don't have much idea about workflow.

(If not possible with **Announcement**, I am ready to move with **Broadcast** list too. Solution I am seeking should be related to **Announcement** or **Broadcast** list.)

Comment: Have you created SharePoint announcement list?

Comment: Yes. I am working with Announcement list..

Comment: Particular user will approve item or those users who have approver permission will able to approve item?

Comment: I am having approver group, the user who are in the group can approve the item.

Comment: Then i think no need to create approval workflow. You can use SharePoint Content Approval feature.Let me know if you required steps to configure Content approval for list.

Comment: If you have steps then you can add it as an answer. It will help me and others also who are seeking for the same information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are the steps to configure Content Approval for list/library.

- Go to the library for which you want to require approval.
- click Library on the ribbon, and then click Library settings in the Settings group.
- Under General Settings, select Versioning settings to open the Versioning Settings page.
- In the Content Approval section, select Yes in answer to the Require content approval for submitted items? In the Document Version History section, specify whether you want SharePoint to create versions when a file is edited. You can also choose to limit the number of versions that are retained.
- In the Draft Item Security section, determine which users can see draft items in the document library.
- Click on OK.

Reference Link: [Require approval of items in a site list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Require-approval-of-items-in-a-site-list-or-library-cd0761c4-8c3f-4ea2-9435-13c28aa23d08)

Comment: I guess you hit the same requirement which I wants. Just one question, can who can approve the items? Can I set my custom selected users as approver?

Comment: No, anyone who is having approver permission on that list/library.